# Javascript = Promise.then : order of resolve in forEach

Tags: javascript, foreach, promise, synchronous

I have a problem managing promises in a foreach loop.

Here a representation of the code I use :

```
function FinalFunction() {
    var list = GetList()
    list.forEach(element => {
        console.log('1');
        myFunction();
        console.log('3');
    }
    console.log('4');
}

function First() {
    queryDB().then(
         function (rs) {
             console.log('2');
         }
    );
}

queryDB = function(sql){
    ...
    connectToDB(cfg).then(
        function(){
            ...
        }
    );
    return def.promise;
}

connectoToDb = function(acfg) {
    fb.attach(acfg, 
        function(err,db) {
            ...
        }
    );
    return def.promise;
}
```

If I have 3 elements in the foreach, in my console I would like

```
1
2
3
1
2
3
1
2
3
4
```

But I have

```
1
3
1
3
1
3
4
2
2
2
```

With the chain of promises.then first>queryDB>connectToDB I can not set up synchronous with await async.

At what point in my chain should I declare it?

Thank you :) !

Comment: I'm having trouble understand what you're asking for here

Comment: please take the time to create a [mre].

Comment: For example, what is `myFunction`? Is it `First`?